# How to read stacked tiff image and write stacked .img image in R

Tags: r, image, tiff, raster

I'm new in R. I want to read stacked tiff image write stacked .img image again in R.  Can anybody guide me step by step in R software? Thank you

Comment: There are a number of packages in R that support reading tiff images, for example the [tiff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tiff) package, [rtiff](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtiff) package, and probably more - you could do a search to see if they support your particular tiff format.

Comment: I have downloaded those packages. I wrote the command in R console window. ndvi2000<-readTIFF("2000_all11_con_filtr2.tif"). Still there is an Error: could not find function "readTIFF".

Comment: You must actually load a package to use it, e.g. `library(tiff)`.

Comment: My image size is 2.6 GB (30 band img). Can R run on such a big file? Or do I need to read them one by one. But I need to use all 30 bands into one process.